# Getting an app to work cross platform between android and iOS in real time

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, ios5

I had an idea for a game app last night that when being played involves a group of friends sitting around together all playing from their smart phones, while a tablet is used for displaying community information. Similar to how the Scrabble game on iOS devices operates, where each player has their rack displayed on their phone, and the game board on the tablet.

My question is, is there a known way to have a setup like that, where users play from their phones onto a tablet, but support it cross-platform? So if 3 players have iphones, 4 are running Android and 2 are using Windows phones with an iPad in the middle, can they all connect and play with each other in real time? Can they connect to each other via blu-tooth perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, not programming related.

AFAIK It's relating to your engine (e.g If you are using Unity3d engine you can publish them to multipe platforms and you can connect them by Unity3d networking class.)